# Some properties of constant functions

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\mathcal F(X, \mathbb R)$ be a collection of real-valued functions defined on a non-empty set $X$. For each $k \in \mathbb R$, let $\hat k \in \mathcal F(X, \mathbb R)$ with $\hat k(x) = k$ for all $x \in X$.

> (1) Show $\mathcal C = \{\hat k: k \in \mathbb R\}$ is a linear subspace of $\mathcal F(X, \mathbb R)$

> (2) Let $\alpha: \mathcal C \to \mathbb R$ as $\alpha(\hat k) = k$. Show $\alpha$ is bijective and for any $k, k' \in \mathbb R, \ \alpha(\hat k + \hat {k'}) = \alpha(\hat k) + \alpha(\hat {k'})$

(1) I just want to see if I understand what they are asking and see if I can do it. By definition, $\hat k$ is in the set of real-valued functions on $X$ and so $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal F(X, \mathbb R)$. Now we just have to show $\mathcal C$ satisfies all the axioms of the real valued vector space. For example, we must show $a \cdot (\hat j + \hat {j'}) = a \cdot \hat j + a \cdot \hat {j'}$ for $a \in \mathbb R, \hat j, \hat {j'} \in \mathcal C$ which is true because by definition of operations on real valued functions $a \cdot (\hat j + \hat {j'})(x) = a((\hat j + \hat {j'})(x)) = a(\hat j(x) + \hat {j'}(x)) = a\hat j(x) + a\hat {j'}(x)$ and $(a \cdot \hat j + a \cdot \hat {j'})(x) = (a \cdot \hat j)(x) + (a \cdot \hat {j'})(x) = a\hat j(x) + a\hat {j'}(x)$. We check the rest of the axioms in a similar manner. **Does that make sense**?

(2) Suppose $\hat k \ne \hat {k'}.$ Then $k \ne k'$ meaning $\alpha(\hat k) \ne \alpha(\hat {k'})$ and so $\alpha$ is injective. By definition, $\hat k$ is defined for all reals and so if $y \in \mathbb R$, there's always $\hat k(x) \in \mathcal C$ that maps to $y$ implying $\alpha$ is surjective. Now, $\alpha(\hat k + \hat {k'})(x) = \alpha(\hat k + \hat {k'})(x)) = \alpha(\hat k(x) + \hat {k'}(x)) = \alpha(\hat k(x)) + \alpha(\hat {k'}(x)) = k + k'$ and $\alpha(\hat k)(x) + \alpha(\hat {k'})(x) = \alpha(\hat k(x)) + \alpha(\hat {k'}(x)) = k + k'.$ **Do these make sense**?

Comment: nitpick: "...be *the* collection of *all* real-valued functions..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since u identified $C$ as a subset of vector space,then it is easier to prove that $C$ is a vector subspace,rather than verifying all the axioms,So u need only to verify that it is not empty(why?),and that it's closed under difference and scalar multiplication.
your proof of injectivity isn't really a proof,since you didn't justify what u are asked to prove,here one possible method:$k=k'\implies \forall x \in \mathbb{R}; \hat{k}(x)=\hat{k'}(x')$ , So $\hat{k}=\hat{k'}$,for surjectivity, given $y$,then $\alpha(\hat{y})=y$, so $\alpha$ is surjective.lastly, u can't apply $\alpha(\hat{k})$ which is a constant to $x$ .

Comment: By definition, $\alpha(\hat k) = \hat k(x) = k$ and so $\alpha(\hat k + \hat{k'}) = (\hat k + \hat {k'})(x) = \hat k(x) + \hat{ k'}(x) = k + k'$. Also, $\alpha(\hat k) + \alpha(\hat {k'}) = \hat k(x) + \hat {k'}(x) = k + k'$. That looks fixed now.